# Positioning In Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, javascript

I made a Wordpress plugin in which I can add a hotel and its details with Google maps. In the plugin I used, the location is not coming in the center of the containing div. It's showing like [this](http://www.screencast.com/users/Bidyut/folders/Default/media/10451777-2b22-40af-aa3e-c16d27e8ecf6).

I need something like [this](http://www.screencast.com/users/Bidyut/folders/Default/media/cffa10f3-9fbb-4ee7-91cf-5e321de8a9b9)

I used the following [code](http://ghsv2.viewthedemo.com/map.php?id=4). I cannot understand what the problem is.

Comment: From the screenshots it looks like you have some kind of CSS overlap problem, but there is no way to help you without some code. In this case, an actual link would be even better, if you can provide a link.

Answer (score 2):

That effect normally occurs when you have dynamically resized the map div or changed its visibility. In either case, you need to trigger the `rezize` event on the map when that occurs.

```
var mapdiv = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
mapdiv.style.display=block;
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Comment: Jolly good: we all said the same thing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731426/google-map-in-wordpress-plugin

Comment: My Problem has solved, actually the problem was when I am shwoing the block in which the map has located then it was not showing. Then I Load the map after the block open  $(document).ready(function(){
 
$(".flip").click(function(){
 
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow", function() {
 
  initialize();
 });
  });
});